# Why do people say "that-a-way" instead of "that way"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, slang

I've often the following:

> Bob: Have you seen Ian ?
>
> Geoff: Yes, he went **that-a-way**.

What is the reason people sometimes jokily add the extra "-a-" into the phrase? Where did this come from? It always makes me think of black-and-white gangster movie chase scenes. But that's probably just me.

Comment: No it is not just you. I also think of cartoons like Bugs Bunny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That-a-way is of British origin and dates from the mid-17th century.

Here's an example from a footnote to Richard Brome's "A Jovial Crew; or, The Merry Beggars" in *[The ancient British Drama](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-b8kAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA203&dq=that-a-way%20OR%20thataway&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aRxoUYPmFdDktQbSw4DAAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=that-a-way%20OR%20thataway%20&f=false)* (1810):

[image: 1i Skise out this away and skisc out that away I should suppose we ought to read Skir out this a way and skir out that a way To skir is to scour to pass hastily So in Macbeth Send out more horses skir the country round Again in King Henry V And make them skir away &c]

> 28 Skise out *this* away, *and* skise out *that* away. — I should suppose we ought to read
>
> " *Skir* out this *a way*, and *skir* out that *a way*."
>
> To *skir* is to *scour*, to pass hastily.

The same play with this same line was also published in 1744 in *[A select collection of old plays](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KDoJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA359&dq=%22skise%20out%20that%20away%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9mdpUfXEAoLn4QTzjICgCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22skise%20out%20that%20away%22&f=false)*:

> .. out again at afternoon, and so 'till supper-time; **skise out this away, and skise out that away** ; (he's no snail I assure you;) and Tantivy all the country over, where hunting, hawking, or any sport is to be made, or good sellowship to be had ; and ...

In fact, [the comedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Jovial_Crew) was first staged in 1641 or 1642 and first published in 1652. Samuel Pepys saw it and wrote in his [diary](http://www.pepysdiary.com/diary/1661/07/25/):

> ... and so I went away with Mr. [Henry] Moore, and he and I to the [King's House] Theatre [Royal], and saw “The Jovial Crew,” the first time I saw it, and indeed it is as merry and the most innocent play that ever I saw, and well performed.

This [side-by-side](http://www.hrionline.ac.uk/brome/viewTranscripts.jsp?type=BOTH&play=JC&act=4) webpage of the 1652 quarto and the modern text includes this on the old side:

> ... Skiſe out this a-
> way, and ſkiſe out that away. (He’s no *Snayle* I as-
> ſure you.)

And for the modern:

> Out again at afternoon, and so till supper–time. Skice out this– a–way, and skice out that–a–way.* — He’s no snail, I assure you.

The asterisk notes:

> ] This edition; Skise out this away, and skise out that away. Q1. OED wrongly identifies 'this-a-way' and 'that-a-way' as nineteenth- and twentieth-century Americanisms indicating direction. See this-a-way, adv., 2, and that-a-way, adv., 2, although the second citation for skice, v.1, is this line in Brome, meaning move quickly; skip or frisk about.

Comment: It's interesting and I hadn't known that the expression is originally British, but I think most Americans associate it with the line "They went that-away" from Western movies.

Answer (score 6):

*That-a-way* is of US origin, and the etymology is straightforward, the term being a combination of *that* and *away*. In the sense ‘in that direction’, the OED’s earliest citation is from 1839. *This-a-way*, meaning ‘in this manner or respect’, is first recorded five years earlier.

**EDIT:** Hugo's answer trumps mine.

Comment: Take a look at the answer below.

Comment: @Robusto. Yes, looks like a previous use. OP may like to transfer the acceptance. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course. He just unaccepts yours and accepts Hugo's. Whether he will or not is up to him.

Comment: Who am I to disagree?